# Dynamic pivot with similar column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, pivot

I'm looking for a way to pivot a varying amount of rows to columns in `sql server 2008 R2`.  I created the data column `RANK` in the query because, ultimately I want the pivoted column names to be labeled the value in the `RANK` column.  Then, if somehow I can `STUFF` the other 3 field values together into one field I would be able to iterate over the row in my backend lang and split the field results appropriately.

Here is the current data set:

[image: data table 1 (original data set)]

And I would like the end result of the pivot to produce a result like this:

[image: data table 2 (end result)]

I haven't found anything about being able to pivot in this "dynamic" way. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK you can't produce a dynamic number of columns without building a query in dynamic SQL. You'd probably build the query in a cursor or while loop whilst iterating the results above

Comment: How are you calculating the `Rank`?  In order to do this you will have to most likely create those `Other` values with `Other1`, `Other2`, etc so they are unique. Once you've done that, then you should be able to pivot those column names.  You will have to do this because you can't have the same name as a new column inside of PIVOT - and you'll need some way to distinguish each row.

Comment: @bluefeet I can absolutely add a digit to the end of `OTHER` but my pivoting problem would still exist, unless you have an idea.  Could you provide an example of what you're thinking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I mentioned above, you need to distinguish each of your `Rank` values.  You've said that this is a calculated value that you can add a number to the end of each one. Once you've added that number, then you still need to pivot it.

The easiest way to first see this would be to write a hard-coded version of the query first.

Sample Data:

```
create table yourdata
(
    id int,
    code varchar(50),
    created datetime,
    [rank] varchar(50)
);

insert into yourdata
select 285856, 'J7609', '2015-01-19', 'Principle' union all
select 285856, 'J7613', '2015-01-19', 'Other' union all
select 285856, 'J0456', '2015-01-19', 'Other' union all
select 285856, 'J0694', '2015-01-19', 'Other' union all
select 285856, 'J1885', '2015-01-19', 'Other' union all
select 285856, 'J2060', '2015-01-19', 'Other' union all
select 285856, 'J2930', '2015-01-19', 'Other';
```

Static Query:

```
select Principle_1, Other_1, 
    Other_2, Other_3, Other_4,
    Other_5, Other_6
from
(
    -- using row_number to get unique id for each rank
    select 
        data = cast(id as varchar(10)) +' | '+ code +' | '+ convert(varchar(10), created, 112),     
        [rank] = [rank] + '_' +cast(row_number() over(partition by id, [rank] 
                                                        order by id) as varchar(10))
    from yourdata
) d
pivot
(
    max(data)
    for [rank] in (Principle_1, Other_1, Other_2, Other_3, Other_4,
                    Other_5, Other_6)
) p;
```

Now to do this dynamic, you will create a sql string with the column names and then execute that string:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT  ',' + QUOTENAME([rank] + '_' +cast(rn as varchar(10))) 
                    from
                    (
                        select [rank],
                            rn = row_number() over(partition by id, [rank] 
                                                    order by id) 
                        from  yourdata
                    ) d
                    group by [rank], rn
                    order by rn, [rank] desc
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT ' + @cols + '
            from 
             (
                select 
                    data = cast(id as varchar(10)) +'' | ''+ code +'' | ''+ convert(varchar(10), created, 112),     
                    [rank] = [rank] + ''_'' +cast(row_number() over(partition by id, [rank] 
                                                                    order by id) as varchar(10))
                from yourdata
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(data)
                for [rank] in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

This gets you a result:

```
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
|        Principle_1        |          Other_1          |          Other_2          |          Other_3          |          Other_4          |          Other_5          |          Other_6          |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
| 285856 | J7609 | 20150119 | 285856 | J7613 | 20150119 | 285856 | J0456 | 20150119 | 285856 | J0694 | 20150119 | 285856 | J1885 | 20150119 | 285856 | J2060 | 20150119 | 285856 | J2930 | 20150119 |
+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+---------------------------+
```

Comment: This is really cool solution and seems to be exactly what I need.  I don't necessarily like the fact that it takes multiple statements to get the job done but I tend to always try and cram everything into one statement (good or bad)... thanks for your help

Comment: @sadmicrowave there are things that just cannot be done with one statement. Like your problem, which needs dynamic SQL. So you need at least 2 statements, one to produce the query and another to run it.